# Syntax Error in mySQL script?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, jenkins, mysql-workbench

So when I run this script

```
mysql -h $mysqlhost -u$mysqluser -p$mysqlpass --database=$mysqldatabase -se "INSERT into $mysqldatabase.$mysqltable (prodID,mergePerformed,mergeStartdate) values ($prodID,'Merge - ${FIX_VERSION} ${BRANCH_TO_MERGE} to ${PROJECT_NAME} trunk', now())";
```

I get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Merge - ${FIX_VERSION} ${BRANCH_TO_MERGE} to ${PROJECT_NAME} trunk', now())' at line 1

Anyone have any thoughts as to why this is...it works when there aren't any variables in jenkins.

Comment: Without knowing Jenkins, my first thought would be the variable substitution isn't working from within the string as you expect.  Would it be possible to put the statement into a variable and output the variable to confirm it's doing the correct substitution?

Comment: Try this : mysql -h $mysqlhost -u $mysqluser --password=$mysqlpass --database=$mysqldatabase -se "INSERT into $mysqldatabase.$mysqltable (prodID,mergePerformed,mergeStartdate) values ($prodID,'Merge - ${FIX_VERSION} ${BRANCH_TO_MERGE} to ${PROJECT_NAME} trunk', now())";

Comment: So your question is "why aren't the variables expanded in Jenkins"? At which point are the variables defined? Which build step are you executing? Can you see the variables when you executed `set` command?

Comment: Seems like PowerShell script, suggest you to print the command and check if any variable value is not assigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can`t see anything wrong as it stands, as xQbert says it is most likely to be some of your variable substitution. 
MySQL syntax errors usually quote the text just after the error, so I would take a look at what is going into $prodID as it is the most likely culprit.